# Reading specific number of characters in a line within a text file and set "read characters" to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, text-files, netbeans-7, jtextarea

I'm trying to read text from text files and I can already print it on system by using system.out.print. But if I set the text of the `JTextArea` from the text that I've read on the text file, it shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException". It's actually running good in printing lines and i can already read what I want but, I can't put this text on `JTextArea`. What should I do?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
package mdiforms;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class trylang extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

/** Creates new form trylang */
public trylang() {
    initComponents();
}



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String path = "C:/Users/Pasusani/Desktop/tawa.txt";
    try {
        // change this value
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
        String CurrentLine;
        while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            processLine(CurrentLine);


        }
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }
}

public static void processLine(String line) {
    // skip header & footer
    //if (line.startsWith("127.0.1.1/dev/sda1")) return;

    String name = line.substring(0, 1);
    String year = line.substring(0, 5);
    System.out.print("Name [" + name + "]\t Year [" + year +"]");
    String ewan = "Name [" + name + "]\t Year [" + year +"]";
    txt_try.setText(ewan);

}

}
```

Comment: where is NPE? which line?

Comment: it's not enough. Post SSCCE to illustrate the problem

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mdiforms.trylang.processLine(trylang.java:110)
at mdiforms.trylang.main(trylang.java:91)
Java Result: 1

Comment: point us the line.. how we will get to know which is line 110 :-)

Comment: Seems your `txt_try` is null define that before call `txt_try.setText(ewan);`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   mdiforms.trylang.processLine(trylang.java:110)
   at mdiforms.trylang.main(trylang.java:91)
   Java Result: 1

Comment: yup. i already know it @alex2410 but i can read and println the lines of text and its actually working but if i set this on JTextArea, it shows the NPE

Comment: LINE 110 sir is the processLine()

Answer (score 2):

`processLine` is a `static` method and here I guess you need to create instance of `trylang` before calling  `txt_try.setText(ewan);`

I am assuming you are initializing `txt_try` in `initComponents();` which is called in `trylang`'s default constructor.

**Sidenote:**

*PLEASE FOLLOW Java naming conventions*

```
txt_try  ==> txtTry
trylang ==> TryLang
```